# WordPress Custom URL for post based page and tags

Tags: custom-post-type, permalinks

This is my site: spreadingbook.com
I have pages named review and quotes,
I have tag same as page name.
I want my post url like: spreadingbook/review(page_name)/post_name(tag=same as page name)
mentioned customization can possible without coding? As coding isn't cup of my tea.

Thanks!

Comment: When asking questions you should try to be a bit more generic and refrain from posting links to external resources (like websites, etc.). Also, it seems unclear as to what the context of this question is and what it has to do with software development?

Comment: sorry to hear that, definitely take care next time.